# How to use a regular expression in this case

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a string-variable (called *string*) matches the following string: *L-62000-64-000_0*

My code looks like this:

```
let string = "L-62000-64-000_05641";
let part = 64;
const filter = new RegExp("^L-\d{5}-${part}-.+");
if (string.match(filter)) {
        console.log("yes");
}
```

It is important, that the string starts with "L-". After this there should be a number with five digits and again a hyphen. The following two digits depend on a variable. After the variable there is again a hyphen. The rest of the string is not important for me. That's why I use the ".+"

The problem is, that this doesn't work and i don't know why...

Comment: `const filter = new RegExp("^L-\\d{5}-" + part + "-.+");`. It does not work because you are using a variable as if you had a template literal, but you are using a regular string literal. Another way: ``const filter = new RegExp(`^L-\\d{5}-${part}-.+`);``

Comment: `let string = L-62000-64-000_05641;` should be `let string = "L-62000-64-000_05641";`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the part variable in the string, you need to use `` instead of ""

```
const filter = new RegExp(`^L-\d{5}-${part}-.+`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add double `\\` in this case

```js
let string = 'L-62000-64-000_05641';
let part = 64;
const filter = new RegExp(`^L-\\d{5}-${part}-.+$`);
if (string.match(filter)) {
        console.log("yes");
} else {
  console.log("no");
}
```